# Reference is not added after installing npm

Tags: angular, toast

I install angualr-ng-autocomplete in angular 8 project but reference of it is not added in package.json file

I use below coomand to install

```
npm i angular-ng-autocomplete --save
```

and If i install npm i ngx-toastr

```
install npm i ngx-toastr
```

angular-ng-autocomplete module from nodumodule is deleted automatically

Answer (score 1):

Please try with yarn temporarily.

```
npm i -g yarn
```

[This seems to be a bug in npm. Refer this link to see if it can help you](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17929)